# What is the result of Matrix A's Frobenius

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's suppose Matrix $A = xp^{T} + yq^{T}$. Meanwhile, $x$, $y$, $p$, $q$ are all column vectors. $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal, $q$ and $p$ are orthogonal. What is the result of $A$'s Frobenius?
[Matrix A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvnjG.gif)

Answer (score 0):

The square of the Frobenius norm is the trace of
$$
AA^T=|p|^2\,xx^T+|q|^2\,yy^T
$$
which is
$$
tr(AA^T)=|p|^2|x|^2+|q|^2|y|^2.
$$